# Return random set of rows from a REGEXP query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, random

I am trying to write a MySQL query that returns a set of random rows based on a REGEXP search on a set of cities.

ie...

```
SELECT * FROM master_rets_table 
          WHERE property_type = "Residential" and city REGEXP "(JUNO BEACH|palm beach gardens|jupiter|WEST PALM BEACH)" and listing_price > 200000 and listing_price < 500000
          GROUP BY city
          ORDER BY RAND()
```

The good news is that this does return one property per city, but it turns out that, I guess, the GROUP BY is eliminated the RANDom aspect of the query because its giving the same results every time.

Comment: No, the `GROUP BY` behavior you are seeing is because of MySQL's allowance of multiple columns in `SELECT` which are not also in `GROUP BY`. Your query would cause a syntax error in almost any other RDBMS.  Can you post a sample of rows from the `master_rets_table` and a sample of what query output you are hoping to get?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: the master_rets_table has over 300 fields, so its not very practical to post it.  what im trying to achieve in one query, if possible, is to grab 4 random properties, one per each city represented in the REGEXP conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get four random properties, one per city is to use `union all`:

```
(select *
 from master_rets_table
 where property_type = "Residential" and city = 'JUNO BEACH' and listing_price > 200000 and listing_price < 500000
 order by rand()
 limit 1
) union all
(select *
 from master_rets_table
 where property_type = "Residential" and city = 'palm beach gardens' and listing_price > 200000 and   listing_price < 500000
 order by rand()
 limit 1
) union all
(select *
 from master_rets_table
 where property_type = "Residential" and city = 'jupiter' and listing_price > 200000 and listing_price < 500000
 order by rand()
 limit 1
) union all
(select *
 from master_rets_table
 where property_type = "Residential" and city = 'WEST PALM BEACH' and listing_price > 200000 and  listing_price < 500000
 order by rand()
 limit 1
)
```

Comment: hmmm very interesting...i've never used a UNION ALL so not only is this answer correct, it has taught me something new.  thanks!